# How to solve TYPO3 error named routes not found?

Tags: routes, typo3

I copied an TYPO3 project locally into XAMPP. The frontend is working correctly, but in the backend the list module is not loading and I am getting this error:

[image: Page module]

The sites configuration module is loading and shows me the entry, but as soon as I want to edit the site configuration a similar error is being displayed:

[image: site configuration module]

I tried to clear the cache, but did't help. Does someone have an idea why that happens?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version? Have you flushed the cache in maintenance module? Have you tried to use the original TYPO3 sources?

Comment: I am using TYPO3 10.4.26. I tried flushing the cache but it didn’t solve the problem. I am also using the original TYPO3 source and linking to it with symlinks…

Comment: "wizard_element_browser" is part of sysext "recordlist". It's required by sysext "backend". But please make sure "recordlist" is activated in extensionmanager or installed via composer. Please check typo3conf/PackageStates.php and tell us, if there is an entry for "recordlist".

Comment: Next check: Visit BE module "Configuration", switch to "Backend Routes" and check, if entry "wizard_element_browser" could be found. If this BE module is not there pease install/activate sysext "lowlevel".

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! Somehow The DB was also damaged. So I deleted everything locally and copied the project again from scratch. After that everything worked again.
But still thank you for your help! It helped me to better understand how TYPO3 works!